# Wordpress: Add border to MC4WP form

Tags: wordpress

I have a MailChimp 4 WordPress signup form embedded in a widget. I am trying to place a border around either the form or the widget on https://www.taastrategies.com/blog/. I used Inspect to identify the form's class as "mc4wp-form mc4wp-form-2449", then added the following to >Appearance >Customize >Additional CSS provided by Generate Press:

```
/* border around mc4wp form */
.mc4wp-form mc4wp-form-2449 {
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

No border appears ... what am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not hitting the right element. It should be `aside#mc4wp_form_widget-2`. Try this code below:

```
aside#mc4wp_form_widget-2 {
    border: 1px solid violet;
    padding: 29px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the corrected element reference works perfectly.